# C# Specflow - BeforeScenario hook is not being called and driver gets null

Tags: c#, binding, hook, specflow

I'm pretty new to Specflow and C#, so I'm facing an issue with specflow hooks.
The problem is: when I use [BeforeScenario], the method is not even called while debugging. 
Removing these hooks and replacing it by [TestInitialize], it works perfectly.
I searched here for solution in many questions, but I didn't find any problem besides something about private methods, which not seems to be my case.

I have 4 classes: Tests, Steps, PageObjects, and Hooks (which contains driver and hooks). 
'Tests' class inherits from 'Steps', which inherits from 'PageObjects', which inherits from 'Hooks'.
Every call is public and I'm writing down some code from 'Hooks' class:

```
 namespace AutomationPractice.Helper
{
    [Binding]
    public class Hooks
    {
        public IWebDriver _driver;

        [BeforeFeature]
        public void BeforeScenario()
        {
            if (_driver == null)
            {
                _driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            else { throw new Exception("Couldn't initialize the driver"); }

        }

        [AfterFeature]
        public void AfterScenario()
        {
            if (_driver != null)
            {
                _driver.Quit();
            }
            else throw new Exception("There was an error while trying to close the driver");

            }
}
}
```

'PageObjects' class:

```
namespace AutomationPractice.PageObjects
{
    [Binding]
    public class GoogleSearchPageObjects : Hooks
    {
        public string goToGooglePage(string url)
        {
            return _driver.Url = url;
        }

        public IWebElement GetTxtSearch()
        {
            return _driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        }

        public void fillTxtSearch(string search)
        {
            GetTxtSearch().SendKeys(search);
        }

    }
}
```

'Steps' class:

```
namespace AutomationPractice.Steps
{
    [Binding]

    public class GoogleSearchSteps : GoogleSearchPageObjects
    {

        [Given(@"I am on google home page")]
        public void GivenIAmOnGoogleHomePage(string url)
        {
            goToGooglePage(url);

        }

        [When(@"I fill the '(.*)' field")]
        public void WhenIFillTheField(string search)
        {
            fillTxtSearch(search);
        }
```

Every class is rounded by [Binding] though.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Fabio, in my code the Hooks class inherits the TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps class. Can you try if this works for you? So public class Hooks : TechTalk.Specflow.Steps {}

Comment: Hi @JeroenLamberts,, unfortunately it does'nt work. Generates a "circular base class dependency between 'GoogleSearchSteps' and 'Hooks'.

Comment: Try removing from `[Binding]` from `Hooks` and `GoogleSearchPageObjects` and run again

Comment: @user1207289, It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many things going on in the same class hierarchy. It would be much simpler to decouple the following things:

- The Web Driver
- The page objects
- Step definitions

You can use SpecFlow's dependency injection framework to wire these things together using constructor arguments.

First your Hooks class where you manage the web driver instance for all step definitions and page objects:

```cs
[Binding]
public class Hooks
{
    private IObjectContainer container;

    public Hooks(IObjectContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void CreateWebDriver()
    {
        var driver = new ChromeDriver();

        container.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(driver);
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void DestroyWebDriver()
    {
        var driver = container.Resolve<IWebDriver>();

        driver.Quit();
        driver.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And the google search page object becomes a separate class that receives a web driver object as a constructor parameter, which decouples it from SpecFlow all together.

```cs
public class GoogleSearchPage
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;

    private IWebElement TxtSearch => driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

    public GoogleSearchPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void EnterSearchTerm(string searchTerm)
    {
        TxtSearch.SendKeys(searchTerm);
    }
}
```

And finally the step definition class, which is where everything gets wired together via the dependency injection framework that comes with SpecFlow:

```cs
[Binding]
public class GoogleSearchSteps
{
    private GoogleSearchPage googleSearch;

    public GoogleSearchSteps(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        googleSearch = new GoogleSearchPage(driver);
    }

    [When(@"I fill the '(.*)' field")]
    public void WhenIFillTheField(string search)
    {
        googleSearch.EnterSearchTerm(search);
    }
}
```

Part of the problem you have right now is the class hierarchy. You are mixing classes that should be separated, but coordinated. By separating the step definitions from the initialization of the web driver, and keeping the page object in its own class you keep the dependencies between these objects organized and limited to exactly what they need (decoupling), and yet still allow them to work together (cohesion).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think you're right about some points, but even trying your solution, I need the `[TestClass]`' and `[TestMethod]` to compile my solution. 
I've tried to put these attributes on `Steps` class, but the debugger was `Unable to get default constructor for the class`.

Comment: I still think there is a problem with Specflow hooks attributes, because, as I said before, the `TestInitialize` worked properly on my first solution.

Comment: @FabioCardoso: Do you have MsTest configured as the unit test framework?

Comment: Yes, I do. I need at least one test framework to build successfully. I tried with NUnit as well..

Comment: it worked! I tried it without the [TestInitialize] attributes before. I was just trying to find out other solutions, but the best solution is yours so far.
I've been studying and things are almost clear for me right now.
I still cant understand the ```IObjectContainer``` thing. I need to take a look at this..
Thank you very much.

Comment: @FabrioCardoso: `IObjectContainer` is from the [BoDi Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BoDi/), which is a light weight [dependency injection framework](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-intro-to-dependency-injection-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-7578c84fa88f/amp/).

Comment: thank you again! I'll take a look deeper into this. Appreciate it.

Comment: can i register the webdriver instance and carry it through other projects? I tried that using specflow, but it didn't work.
So i got ```BoDi.ObjectContainerException: 'Interface cannot be resolved: OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver ```

Comment: did you find a solution to this last comment?

Comment: @FabioCardoso: You cannot share web driver instances across projects. It is an object created at runtime, so each SpecFlow test project will need its own "hooks" file to create the web driver before each test.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods are names `BeforeScenario` and `AfterScenario`, but you are using the attributes for `BeforeFeature` and `AfterFeature`.
These have to be static that they will be called.

You need to change the attributes.

Comment: This is not the problem. Even using [BeforeScenario], even changing to static, doesn't work